# Solving the pde $f_x(x,y)+f_y(x,y)=0$ given $f(x,0)=\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose, $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that,
$f_x(x,y)+f_y(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2.$ If $f(x,0)=\sin x$ then, find $f(0,y).$

A quick look reveals that $f(x,y)=\sin(x-y) $ is a solution, so $f(0,y)=-\sin y,$ but I got this only by inspection. I am not sure whether this is the only solution to the above pde, I am new to this area, so please help me.

Comment: Using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), the characteristic curves come from the relations $$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{1} = \frac{df}{0}$$ The last quotient gives $f = C_{2} = g(C_{1})$ for some arbitrary differentiable function $g$ and the $C_{i}$ are constants. We also have $$x - y = C_{1}$$ from the first equality and hence the solution is $f = g(x - y)$. As you have shown, using the initial condition then gives $f = \sin(x - y)$ and hence $f(0, y) = - \sin y$.

Comment: If $f(x,y)=e^{ax+by}$ then $f_x+f_y=(a+b)f.$ So you need $a+b=0.$ Since $f(x,0)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right),$ you get $$f(x,y)=\frac1{2i}\left(e^{i(x-y)}-e^{-i(x-y)}\right)=\sin(x-y).$$

Comment: More general, if $g$ is any differentiable function, then $f(x,y)=g(x-y)$ is a solution to the differential equation, without the $f(x,0)$ condition. So if we let $F(x,y)=f(x,y)-f(x-y,0)$ you have a function with $$F_x+F_y=0, F(x,0)=0.$$ You can probably show that $F$ is identically $0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews , can you tell me how to show that $F\equiv 0?$

Comment: @mattos I don't get the meaning of your solution, at one stage you are showing that $f=C_2$ is a constant , also you have shown $f=g(x-y)$ for some differentiable function $g$, I don't get it.

Comment: I said “can probably.” I don’t do differential equations much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $f(x,y)=\sin(x-y)$ is the only solution. Here is a proof.

Let $g(z,y)=f(z+y,y)$ for $z,y\in\mathbb R$, then by chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(z,y)=f_x(x+y,y)+f_y(x+y,y)=0.$$
Hence for any fixed $z$, the function $y\mapsto g(z,y)$ is constant, so
$$g(z,y)=g(z,0)=f(z,0)=\sin z.$$
Now writing $x=z+y$, we get $z=x-y$ and
$$f(x,y)=f(z+y,y)=g(z,y)=\sin z=\sin(x-y).$$
Therefore, $f(0,y)=-\sin y$.

Comment: Nice solution. However, I would like to know is there any theory for linear pde, which will tell us, when there will be unique solution? @mattos used method of characteristic curves, which I don't understand fully, if you know how to procceed along those lines, please write it down, your trick is quite nice , Thomas Andrews also tried to employ similiar tricks.

Comment: @AaaikomBaaikom What I used is exactly the method of characteristic curves, which is a very useful method to convert a first-order linear PDE to an ODE, and then get its solution. I just wrote my answer in a way which is easier to understand. As you can see, the key point is to show that $f$ is constant along the lines $y\mapsto (x+y,y)$, which is exactly the characteristic curves. I recommend you two books to read for a comprehensive understanding of this method. They are: *PDEs: An Introduction* by W.A. Struss, Chapter 14  and  *PDEs* by L.C. Evans, Section 2.1 & Section 3.2.

Comment: @AaaikomBaaikom About the uniqueness of PDEs, unfortunately, there are no general theories. Different equations have very different properties; even if they have a similar property, *e.g.* uniqueness, the proofs can be very different. The book I mentioned before written by Evans, Chapter 2,6,7 deal with some typical types of  linear PDEs which are very common. I highly recommend you to learn about that. It may be a liitle hard for you to understand, but it deserves your time, and you will learn a lot from that.

Comment: Thanks @Feng for your illuminating comments. I shall upvote your answer. You have suggested me two books, which one is written in a motivating manner rather than Bourboki style? also is there any book written on ode/pde which is more inclined towards Geometry? Thank you again. Now , I can appreciate and understand the solution provided by mattos.

Comment: @AaaikomBaaikom Struss’s book is not-so-Bourboki, you may try that. Doing math, especially *analysis*, motivation is not enough, we need rigorous things. Recall the definition of limits, the motivation of which is obvious: $a_n$ converges to $A$ means $a_n$ infinitely approach $A$; but this cannot even be used, we need a rigorous definition and that’s why $\epsilon-N$ has to be used in problems. So, don’t be afraid of rigorous mathematical formulas, fighting for it (see the quote in my file page)! Indeed, I don’t any PDE book easier to understand than Struss. I don’t know much about geometry..

Comment: @AaaikomBaaikom If you are not satisfied by my above comment and still want some introductory books on PDEs through a geometric point of view, you may ask a new question, and more experts on geometric PDEs will help you. Finally, my answer is a “converse” version of mattos’ proof in the comment, now you can understand both: Mattos’ is about motivation, mine is about rigor. If you think my answer is nice, you can consider upvoting and then accepting it by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. That’s how this site works.